# Non-Linear Techniques

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This Question is a practice exercise assigned to us. I have the answer but I don't find it very intuitive. The answer I have is on this pdf : http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/math53h/solution5.pdf

Find a global change of coordinates that linearizes the system

$x' = x + y^2$

$y' = −y$

$z' = −z + y^2$

**Please do not give negative rating before giving me a chance to make corrections if any errors are found in the question.**

Comment: "Please do not give negative rating before giving me a chance to make corrections if any errors are found in the question." +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are asked to find a global change of coordinates that linearizes the nonlinear system:

$\tag 1 x' = x + y^2$

$\tag 2 y' = −y$

$z\tag 3' = −z + y^2$

From $(2)$, we get:

$\tag 4 y = y_0 e^{-t}$ (You know how to solve this, correct?)

Lets now substitute this into $(1)$ and solve that DEQ:

We have $x' - x = y^2 = (y_0 e^{-t})^2 = y_0^2 e^{-2t}$. Lets work the details of this one as a sample manually.

Homogeneous: $m - 1 = 0 \rightarrow m = 1 \rightarrow x_h = x_0e^t$

Particular: Assume $x_p = Ae^{-2t}$, so $x' - x = -2Ae^{-2t} - A e^{-2t} = y_0^2 e^{-2t}$, so $-3A = y_0^2 \rightarrow A = -\frac{1}{3} y_0^2$.

Thus, we get $x = x_h+x_p, so$:

$\tag 5 \displaystyle x(t) =  x_0 e^t - \frac{1}{3} y_0^2e^{-2t}.$

Lets now repeat this process for $(3)$ and solve that DEQ:

We have $z' + z = y^2 = (y_0 e^{-t})^2 = y_0^2 e^{-2t}$, and solving for $z$ yields:

$\tag 6 z(t) =  z_0 e^{-t} - y_0^2e^{-2t}.$

Next, our goal is to get rid of the nonlinear terms in $x, y$ and $z$ by finding a 'global change of coordinates'.

What if we choose a change a variables that guarantees those nonlinear terms disappear? How can we do that?

Let: $\displaystyle u = x + \frac{y^2}{3} = x_0 e^t - \frac{1}{3} y_0^2e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{3} y_0^2e^{-2t} = x_0e^t.$

So, we have: $u = x_0e^t$.

If you take the derivative of $u$, what do you get?

$u' = x_0e^t$. In other words $u' = u.$ (That nicely linearized.)

Next, if we let: $v = y = y_0e^{-t}$, what is $v'$? Well, $v' = -y_0e^{-t} = -v$. (That nicely linearized.)

If we let (note - there is a slight typo in the solution key here, they meant $y^2$):

$w = z + y^2 = z_0e^{-t} -y_0^2e^{-2t} + y_0^2e^{-2t} = z_0e^{-t}.$

If we take the derivative of this, we get $w' = -z_0e^{-t} = -w$. (That nicely linearized.)

We are now left with a linearized system:

$\tag 7 u' = u$

$\tag 8 v' = -v$

$\tag 9 w' = -w$

They wrote the solution in a very compact/condensed form and maybe that was throwing you off. I would recommend comparing the above with what they wrote and make sure it is clear!

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank @Amzoti. I am still reviewing the answer.

Comment: Take your time and go through each step - rewrite it and ask if any step is confusing! Regards

Comment: So very thorough $+1^{\infty}$ for all that work!

Comment: @amWhy: thank you. I can see how the solution could be confusing the way it was written, maybe that was intentional to let them work through the details, but interesting problems nonetheless! Regards

Comment: It's nice when we can combine being helpful and finding the question interesting, at the same time ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti why do you have 1/3 in step (5). This may be something obvious but I cant grasp it.

Comment: @KjTada: see my update to the answer. Just assume a particular soultion, take $x' - x = x_p$ and solve for constant (see answer above). Regards

Comment: Seems slow tonight (for me anyway). Will need to head to bed soon, but I was hoping Babak would "appear" before that!

Comment: @amWhy: Agreed - I have been editing, doing reviews and listening to good music! Slow night, and I have not seen Babak ina couple of days. Have a great night - getting close to bedtime for me too!